# using wp_enqueue_script breaks script in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

If I use the full path to a script in the head section of my Wordpress theme it works fine. E.g.:

```
<script src="http://www.mysite.com/wp-content-/theme/mytheme/js/script.js"></script>
```

However, if I use the 'correct' Wordpress method it breaks, e.g.:

```
<?php wp_enqueue_script('kwicks-settings', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js'); ?>
```

When i use the wp_enqueue_script, the script appears linked to in the source code, but for some reason the script doesn't run.

Any ideas why this might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't registering the script.

Register it:

```
wp_register_script( 'my-script', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/myscript.js');
```

Then Enqueue it:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script' );
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to register your script.
Then you need to describe dependent scripts as well (in this example: if your script require jquery library).

So correct usage is :

```
wp_register_script('kwicks-settings', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js', array('jquery') );
wp_enqueue_script('kwicks-settings');
```